# Is there a way to prevent Maven Test from rebuilding the database?

Tags: java, maven-2, junit, dbunit

I've recently been asked to, effectively, sell my department on unit testing.  I can't tell  you how excited this makes me, but I do have one concern.  We're using JUnit with Spring and Maven, and this means that each time `mvn test` is called, it rebuilds the database.  Obviously, we can't integrate that with our production server -- it would kill valuable data.

How do I prevent the rebuilding without telling maven to skip testing?

The best I could figure was to assign the script to operate in a test database (line breaks added for readability):

```
mvn test 
   -Ddbunit.schema=<database>test 
   -Djdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database>test?
        createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;
        useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

I can't help but think there must be a better way.

I'm especially interested in learning if there is an easy way to tell Maven to only run tests on particular classes without building anything else?  `mvn -Dtest=<test-name> test` still rebuilds the database.

======= update =======

Bit of egg on my face here.  I didn't realize that I was using the same variable in two places, meaning that the POM was using a "skip.test" variable for both rebuilding the database and for running the tests...

Comment: It's not a "unit test" if it touches a live production database

Comment: Knowing how dbunit and Spring are being initialized for the unit tests would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I guess that DBUnit does the rebuilding of the DB because it is told to do so in the test setup method. If you change your setup method, you can eliminate the DB rebuild. Of course, you should do it so that you get the DB reset when you need it, and omit it when you don't. My first bet would be to use a system property to control this. You can set the property on the command line the same way you already do with `jdbc.url` et al. Then in the setup method you add an `if` to test for that property and do the DB reset if it is set.

A test database, completely separated from your production DB is definitely the best choice if you can have it. You can even use e.g. [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), an in-memory DB which can run embedded within the JVM. But in case you absolutely can't have a separate DB, use at least a separate test schema inside that DB.

In this scenario I would recommend you put your DB connection parameters into profiles within your pom, the default being the test DB, and a separate profile to contain the production settings. This way it can never happen that you accidentally run your tests against the production DB.

In general, however, it is also important to understand that tests run against a DB are not really unit tests in the strict sense, rather integration tests. If you have an existing set of such tests, fine, use them as much as you can. However, you should try to move towards adding more real unit tests, which test only a small, isolated portion of your code at once (a method or class at most), ideally self contained (need no DB, net, config files etc.) so they can run fast - this is a very important point. If you have 5000 unit tests and each takes only 5 seconds to run, that totals up to almost 7 hours, so you obviously won't run them very often. If a test takes only 5 milliseconds, you get the results in less than half a minute, so you can afford to run all your tests before you commit your latest change - many times a day. That makes a huge difference in the speed of feedback you get from the tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See the update: I need mvn to build the classes, but I can't simply call "build and test without touching the (temporary/testing) database"

Answer (score 1):

> We're using JUnit with Spring and Maven, and this means that each time mvn test is called, it rebuilds the database.

Maven doesn't do anything with databases by itself, your code does. In any case, it's very unusual to run tests (which are not unit tests) against a production database.

> How do I prevent the rebuilding without telling maven to skip testing?

Hard to say without more details (you're not showing anything) but profiles *might* be a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests, by definition, only operate on a single component in the system. You should not be attempting to write unit tests which integrate with any external services (web, DB, etc.). The solution I have to this is to use a good mocking framework to stub out the behaviour of any dependencies your components have. This encourages good interface APIs since most mocking frameworks work best with simple interfaces. It would be best to create a Repository pattern interface for any interactions with your DB and then mock out the impl any time you are testing a class that interacts with it. You can then functionally test your Repository impl separately. This also has the added benefit of keeping your unit tests fast enough to remain part of your CI so that your feedback cycle is as fast as possible.